# Генерация DOC файла с картинками C#

Tags: c#, doc, generate

Есть Desctop приложение на WPF.
Я генерирую картинки штрих-кодов. Как мне создать *.doc файл и при генерации Image файла добавлять в него эти штрих-коды? Картинки штрих-кодов удобно помещаются в документ по 2 на строчку.

Нужно примерно следующее:

1. Добавляем картинку
2. Добавляем 10 пробелов
3. Добавляем вторую картинку
4. Переходим на новую строчку и пока есть элементы заново с первого пункта

Какие есть nuget пакеты для генерации Doc где можно было бы размещать в таком вот порядке картинки?

Код генерации штрих-кодов:

```
private void SaveBarcodes()
{
    var barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Image image = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128B, item.Barcode.ToString(), Color.Black, Color.White, 290, 120);

        // Тут нужно добавлять полученную картинку в документ.
        // var doc
    }

    // После того как документ сгенерируется, сохраняем его.
}
```

Comment: Формат doc (устаревший) или всё-таки docx (новый)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov без разницы какой формат, можно и тот и тот. Офис 2016 стоит.

Comment: _Сколько вешать граммов?_ Повторяю вопрос: какой именно формат? Они совершенно разные _внутри_. А в принципе, идёте на nuget.org, вводите соответственно doc или docx в строку поиска, выбираете понравившуюся библиотеку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне нужен этот файл только для того что бы распечатать его на принтере. Какой именно файл открывать для печать разницы нет, пускай будет docx. Нашел на nuget DocX,  но не вижу примеров его использования нигде. Есть какие-то мануалы по работе с данными пакетами?

Comment: Оказывается, вам не нужен вордовский документ... Не проще ли печатать изображения напрямую из WPF?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а каким образом можно печатать напрямую, что бы бумагу не переводить и документ для печати имел такой вид как я описал?

Comment: Есть два варианта реализации. 1) берём docx с **любой** картинкой в тексте, и тупо в архиве перетираем картинку (нерекомендую, потому что штрихкод может получится размытым, возможно прийдется експерементировать). 2)Находим в шрифте знаки `"█","▌","▐"`  и печатаем их в тексте выбрав желательно моноширинный шрифт (Courier New например). Переработав картинку - полосочки можно получить хороший штрихкод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал сохранение в PDF файл с помощью библиотеки [**iTextSharp**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/):

```
private void OnSaveSelectedCells()
{
    var barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();

    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog { FileName = "Barcodes", Filter = "PDF file (*.pdf)|*.pdf" };

    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var document = new Document();

        var fileStream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

        // Для отображения русских букв
        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        var font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, 14);

        document.Open();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var imageBarcode = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128B, item.Barcode, Color.Black, Color.White, 290, 120);

            var image = Image.GetInstance(imageBarcode, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            document.Add(new Paragraph(item.Description, font));
            document.Add(image);
        }

        document.Close();
        // Открытие созданного файла
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(saveFileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```